# How to completely disable/remove option of "Merge Immediately" in merge requests?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

We have a requirement in which Developers should compulsorily run merge train before merging their merge requests.  But for that, I need to disable the option of "Merge Immediately" in all repos.  Is there a way to do that ?  I search a lot on google but did not find any proper solution for this.